# SW to urdf converter: errors in links masses

Tags: urdf, solidworks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
We have used the SW to urdf converter to obtain the model of a 6 dof arm robot (6 links). The converetr works well but we found that the masses calculated for each link correspond to the mass of the entire robot. It seems that the same is happening with moments of inertia.
Does anybody know if there is a mistake in the converter?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48938/sw-to-urdf-converter:-errors-in-links-masses/) by [Maddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3654/maddi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the question. Yes, this was a bug, you may have been the one to email me about it. It was addressed in V1.0 Build 4714.35040. Download the latest version and reinstall.

---

Originally posted by [brawner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2146/brawner/) with karma: 581 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1